# Include a pre-built version of dygraphs in the repo?

Tags: javascript, dygraphs

I install Dygraphs via bundler to include in my app. I don't use any server side Javascript tooling other than bundler for simple dependency management. I went to upgrade to Dygraphs 2 and noticed that the dist folder is gone and, as far as I can tell, Dygraphs no longer ships a prebuilt version. I tried following the build directions but I'm pretty unfamiliar with node et al and couldn't get it working.

Any chance we could get a pre-built versiob included in the repo again for bower users?